# Switch source method for object created in Using block

Tags: c#

I have a process that is to be used to load data from various sources to a SQL Server database. Within the process, I have several methods that each consume file data and return a DataTable object. Depending on the type of data to be loaded, one of these methods is called for any single run of the process.

All of the DataTable objects created by these methods are consumed by the same target method, which transfers the data to SQL Server. This has led to some duplication of code:

```
if (useDT == 1)
        {
            using (DataTable dt = MakeDT1())
            {
                ConsumeDT(dt);
            }
        }

        if (useDT == 2)
        {
            using (DataTable dt = MakeDT2())
            {
                ConsumeDT(dt);
            }
        }
```

(Simplified for clarity, real world names are descriptive)

I'd like to avoid this if at all possible. Is it possible to pre-calculate the correct method to call to generate the DataTable, then call ConsumeDT(dt) just once? E.g.

```
 switch (useDT)
            {
                case 1
                    dtCall = MakeDT1()
                    break;

                case 2
                    dtCall = MakeDT2()
            }

            using (DataTable dt = dtCall)
            //etc
```

Thanks in advance, Iain

Comment: Actually there is no reason to dispose a `DataTable`

Comment: I don't mind the -1 but it would be helpful to know why it was given, so that I can try to be better next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a little helper method that returns the correct kind of DT object:

```
private DataTable makeDt(bool useDT)
{
    return useDT ? MakeDT1() : MakeDT2();
}
```

And then call that in the `using` like so:

```
using (var dt = makeDt(useDt))
{
    ConsumeDT(dt);
}
```

This has the advantage of assigning the disposable `dt` inside a `using` making it unlikely that someone will write code that could cause a leak.

Comment: This is the *cleaner* whay to do for sure!

Comment: Thanks, Matthew, that does just what I need (with a tweak to use explicit if blocks due to having more than 2 methods that generate a DataTable)

Answer (score 2):

You can leave out the using block, you'll just have to make sure to correctly dispose the object in the end:

```
DataTable dt;
switch(useDT) {
    case 1: dt = MakeDT1(); break;
    case 2: dt = MakeDT2(); break;
}
try {
    ConsumeDt(dt);
} finally {
    dt.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note that in this code, if ConsumeDt() throws an exception, dt will not be disposed.  That's a moot point because you don't really need to dispose a DataTable. But if it was another type that you really DID need to dispose, this could be significant.

Comment: Thanks, I was in a rush and didn't think of that... I have edited my asnwer accordingly.